# Can't find logic error, and need a second pair of eyes

Tags: c++

Hi I'm working on this acm problem, and I can't seem to figure out why my algorithm isn't working.

https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=482

My sillySort function is supposed to be finding all the different subarrays, and then minimizing the sum of the swapped values.

My output is very close to their output, but I'm not sure what's wrong. I have sat down and even written the problem out on a whiteboard. Can anyone spot it?

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int* array, int index1, int index2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
}

void printArray(int* array, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

int sillySort(int* array, int size)
{
    int minSum = 0;
    bool firstSwap = true;

    printArray(array, size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int i2 = i + 1; i2 < size; i2++)
        {
            //Found a swappable pair
            if(array[i] > array[i2])
            {
                int sum = array[i] + array[i2];
                std::cout << "Swapping: " << array[i] << " and " << array[i2]  << " (" << sum << ")" << std::endl;

                //Temporary swap the array to call silly on it
                swap(array, i, i2);

                //Calculate silly on new array
                int minSilly = sillySort(array, size);

                //Found a new minimum
                if((minSilly + sum) < minSum || firstSwap)
                {
                    firstSwap = false;
                    minSum = minSilly + sum;
                }

                //Move array back into position
                swap(array, i, i2);
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Returning: " << minSum << std::endl;
    return minSum;
}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 6;
    int array[arraySize];
    array[0] = 8;
    array[1] = 4;
    array[2] = 5;
    array[3] = 3;
    array[4] = 2;
    array[5] = 7;

    std::cout << sillySort(array, arraySize) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try with const int arraySize = 7;

Comment: Won't that go out of bounds since the array is only size 6, and the last index is 5?

Comment: Yes it will, I have no idea why @Himanshu would suggest that, especially with no explanation.

Comment: `I have sat down and even written the problem out on a whiteboard.` share your research! we don't know what you know ;-)

Comment: What is "their output"?

Comment: I think your problem is with your "swappable pair" test. The lowest swap sequence is to swap 2 and 7, then 8 and 2, but your algorithm won't consider swapping 2 and 7 as 2 <= 7

Comment: @TheDark: Suppose the optimal sequence involves swapping two elements from the correct order to the incorrect order (e.g ...,2,7 => ...,7,2) which we'll call a "funny swap". Now skip that swap and perform all the others (by site, not by element); you'll wind up with the sequence sorted except those two elements will be reversed. Now swap those two *in an unfunny swap*, with the same cost as if you had performed the funny swap. So if the sorting can be done with a funny swap, it can be done for the same cost without that funny swap. So there is no need to consider funny swaps.

Comment: @Beta maybe I am misunderstanding - If the first two swaps with [indexes] were (2[4],7[5]) and (8[0], 2[5]) would that mean you skip the 2,7 (index 4 and 5) swap and then swap 8,7 (index 0 and 5) - that would cost 15. The end result would be sorted, but the total cost would be more.

Comment: @TheDark: Hmm... No, it's not that you misunderstand, it's that my proof is no damned good.

Comment: @Beta in this case their output is 34, mine was around 39.

Comment: @Dark I don't think you should have to swap 2 and 7 because then that will move greater numbers towards the front of the array.

Answer (score 0):

That was an interesting problem!

Consider the second sample case:  the 4-element array is 8124. (It was easier to solve for a 4-element array than a 7-element array; and your program didn't get the best answer on that one either.)

The correct answer of the best cost is 17.  Here is a sequence of moves (and I'm sure it's unique, but haven't proved it) that will get you a sorted list with a cost of 17.

```
Swap 1 and 2.  Cost is 3.  New sequence is 8214.
Swap 1 and 4.  Cost is 5.  New sequence is 8241.
Swap 1 and 8.  Cost is 9.  New sequence is 1248 (sorted).
```

Total cost is 17.

Your program can't get there because it only swaps elements when they are in the wrong order.  My first swap moved 1 to appear after 2, which changed them from the right order to the wrong order... but that move is on the way to the right, and minimal-cost, solution.

So the solution is to **relax the assumption that you must only swap things that are out of order**.  (You'll also need to restructure your algorithm, since that assumption is currently the only thing that prevents infinite recursion.)